# vba, soap webservice incomplete response

Tags: vba, web-services, soap, exchangewebservices

i am trying to get a large data of stock market by soap 1.1 envelope request, the structure of webservice explained in this link:
http://service.tsetmc.com/WebService/TsePublicV2.asmx?op=BestLimitsAllIns

it is my code:

```
sub downloaddata()    
Dim Url As String
Url = "http://service.tsetmc.com/WebService/TsePublicV2.asmx"
Dim fldr As String
fldr = "C:\Users\daily\"
'init variable values
Dim Response As String
'Build the HTTP Request object
Dim ObjHttp As New MSXML2.XmlHttp
'build soap envelope for fetching header
Dim sEnv As String
sEnv = "<?xml version=" & """" & "1.0" & """" & " encoding=" & """" & "utf-8" & """" & "?>"
sEnv = sEnv & "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=" & """" & "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" & """" & " xmlns:xsd=" & """" & "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" & """" & " xmlns:soap=" & """" & "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" & """" & ">"
sEnv = sEnv & "<soap:Body>"
sEnv = sEnv & "<BestLimitsAllIns xmlns=" & """" & "http://tsetmc.com/" & """" & ">"
sEnv = sEnv & "<UserName>" & """" & "username" & """" & "</UserName>"
sEnv = sEnv & "<Password>" & """" & "password" & """" & "</Password>"
sEnv = sEnv & "<Flow>" & "0" & " </Flow>"
sEnv = sEnv & "</BestLimitsAllIns>"
sEnv = sEnv & "</soap:Body>"
sEnv = sEnv & "</soap:Envelope>" 
'wrap the http request in a with statement
With ObjHttp
    .Open "post", Url, False
    .setRequestHeader "Host", "service.tsetmc.com"
    .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8"
    .setRequestHeader "Content-Length", Len(sEnv)
    .setRequestHeader "SOAPAction", "http://tsetmc.com/BestLimitsAllIns"
    .send sEnv
    Response = ObjHttp.responseText
    Debug.Print "111111111111111111111111"
    Debug.Print .getAllResponseHeaders
    Debug.Print .responseText
    Debug.Print .Status
    Debug.Print .statusText
End With
Dim XDoc As MSXML2.DOMDocument
Dim xEmpDetails As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
Dim xParent As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
Dim xChild As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
Dim Col, Row As Integer
Set XDoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument
XDoc.async = False
XDoc.validateOnParse = False
If Not XDoc.LoadXML(Response) Then  'strXML is the string with XML'
    Err.Raise XDoc.parseError.ErrorCode, , XDoc.parseError.reason
End If
XDoc.LoadXML (Response)
Set xEmpDetails = XDoc.DocumentElement
Set xParent = xEmpDetails.FirstChild
Row = 2
Col = 1
For Each xParent In xEmpDetails.ChildNodes
    For Each xChild In xParent.ChildNodes
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("a").Cells(Row, Col).Value = xChild.Text
        Col = Col + 1
    Next xChild
    Row = Row + 1
    Col = 1
Next xParent
End Sub
```

the response should be this:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
    <BestLimitsAllInsResponse xmlns="http://tsetmc.com/
    <BestLimitsAllInsResult>
        <xsd:schema>schema(real content will be replaced) 
        </xsd:schema>xml(real content will be replaced
        </BestLimitsAllInsResult>
    </BestLimitsAllInsResponse>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

but the real response i've given is just a part of sample and the main data have not shown:

```
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
Content-Length: 301
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Sat, 06 Oct 2018 05:23:47 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body
<BestLimitsAllInsResponse xmlns="http://tsetmc.com/" /></soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
200 
OK
```

the response is incomplete, the main data in 4 line above is missing. i don't know why i can't debug the problem. please check it and help me. thank you

Comment: what do you mean `i don't know why i can't debug the problem`?

Comment: i mean "why the response is incomplete and the main data is missing?"

Comment: here in this line should be stock data but it does not: <BestLimitsAllInsResponse xmlns="http://tsetmc.com/" /></soap:Body>

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure, Are you sure you're using valid userid & password?  ...because with a made up userid & password I got the same response as you.  I'd suggest contacting the source of the API directly.

Comment: thank you, i'll check the user and pas directly and retry

Comment: i contact the source of API directly and they confirm my user and pas, they get data correctly too. so what is problem? :((

Comment: Status code is `301`, not `200`. You are already `debug.print`ing the response's headers, so check for 'Location' response header. Seems like you are being served a permanent redirect.

Comment: thank you so much, i added line "Debug.Print .getResponseHeader("Location")" but nothing 
 apears, why status code is 301? it seems 301 is the length of response. what can i do else?

Comment: problem has been solved. thanks